# How to prevent android webview load images?

Tags: android, image, webview

How to prevent android webview load images?

I give user an option whether to load images or not in a webview.

One option is to using regex to delete all image tags. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score -1):

This should help you with all settings regarding a webview: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html

Comment: You should really put the relevant parts **in** your answer. It's good practice for "link" answers.

Comment: True. However I'm currently on mobile, and navigating the android dev site is buggy on my phone. Hopefully, this link provides more resources to help the user with all of their questions regarding webview